# Bedeutung von "fresslich"

Tags: meaning

> Unsere Kantine kümmert sich um euer ***fressliches Wohl***

Was bedeutet "fresslich" in diesem Kontext und gibt es überhaupt solch ein Wort?

Comment: *»Gibt es überhaupt solch ein Wort?«* Ja natürlich. Es steht ja da. Ich kann es deutlich sehen, und du selbst hast es geschrieben. Es gibt kein Amt, das neue Wörter genehmigen muss, oder das neue Wörter herausgibt. Jede Buchstabenkette, die den urtümlichsten Zweck jeder Sprache erfüllt (Information vom Sender zum Empfänger transportieren) ist ein Wort. Man kann fragen, ob das Wort gängig ist, oder ob es die Quelle von Missverständnissen sein kann. Aber wenn ein Wort von irgendjemandem verwendet wird, um seine Gedanken auszudrücken, ist es bereits ein echtes und ganz real existierendes Wort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nein, das Wort "*fresslich*" gibt es nicht. (Also streng genommen gibt es das Wort natürlich schon, es wurde ja in der Frage geschrieben.) Aber man kann es als kreative Wortschöpfung betrachten, die sich auch mit einer Internetsuche finden lässt.

Der Ausdruck der in diesem Zusammenhang üblicherweise verwendet wird ist

> Unsere Kantine kümmert sich um euer **leibliches Wohl**.

Comment: Wie kann man behaupten, dieses Wort gäbe es nicht, wenn es allein auf dieser Seite mindestens achtmal verwendet wird? Der Spiegel titelte einmal [Fressliche Weihnachten!](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/literatur/comic-adventskalender-fressliche-weihnachten-a-804960.html) Das Wort ist nicht einmal neu, es taucht schon im 17. Jahrhundert [in einem Buch](https://books.google.at/books?id=5ZVYAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PP39&lpg=RA1-PP39&dq=fresslich&source=bl&ots=ApAWmIVtbX&sig=NwjkjxnTNY3C2yu7zGmUPwCqxKo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC5f_8lqTWAhUBY1AKHW3WAtEQ6AEIUzAJ#v=onepage&q=fresslich&f=false) auf.

Comment: Das Wort ist einfach nur selten (und wie ich finde hässlich), aber das Wort gibt es.

Comment: Es ist kein offiziell gebräuchliches Wort der deutschen Sprache. Es ist nur eine kreative Wortschöpfung. Es ist wie "Meinereiner" für "ich".

Comment: Wer auch immer den Downvote hier gegeben hatte sollte sich überlegen, ob der Downvote nach dem jetzt erfolgten Edit noch Gültigkeit hat.

Comment: @äüö: Oh, du hast eine *offizielle* Liste der gebräuchlichen Wörter der deutschen Sprache gefunden? Du meinst aber nicht zufällig das [Wörterverzeichnis des Rechtschreibrats](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Woerterverzeichnis_2017.pdf)? Etwas noch offizielleres kann ich mir nämlich nicht vorstellen, leider ist diese Liste aber unvollständig. Ich kann darin aber weder *Handy* noch *Brexit* finden, höre und lese aber beide Wörter fast täglich. Dort ein Wort nicht zu finden würde ich daher nicht als Beweis dafür ansehen, dass das Wort kein offiziell gebräuchliches Wort ist.

Comment: Blödsinn, Muttersprachler brauchen für diese Einschätzung keine Wortlisten von Räten. Denke nach, wie oft du im Leben schon "fresslich" verwendet hast! Ich wette nie, und du wirst es auch nicht von deinen Mitmenschen gehört haben. Das allein rechtfertigt "kein offiziell gebräuchliches".

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort *fresslich* existiert offensichtlich tatsächlich schon sehr lange, ist nur nicht sonderlich gebräuchlich (danke an Hubert Schölnast für die Korrektur).

Ich versuche mal kurz den Hintergrund dieser Wortschöpfung beleuchten:

**Fressen** ist der Vorgang des Essens bei Tieren. Es wird auch abschätzig für Menschen verwendet, die *wie Tiere* essen (schmatzen, rülpsen, Essen auf den Boden schmeißen, etc.).

Für Haustiere wird auch häufig die Verniedlichung **Fresschen** (sprich Fress-chen) verwendet.

Bei Menschen wird der Ausdruck *Fressen* häufig in Zusammenhang mit durch Feste oder Feiertage induzierter Völlerei benutzt: **Ich habe mich wieder völlig überfressen** als Ausdruck der Tatsache, dass man z.B. an Weihnachten den ganzen Tag nur am Essen zu sein scheint...

Der Ausdruck *fressliches Wohl* ist hier nicht beleidigend / despektierlich, sondern humoristisch gemeint um auszudrücken: Es geht ums Essen.

Ich vermute eine Wortschöpfung eines kreativen Kantinenmitarbeiters oder eines sogenannten *Marketingexperten*.

Es gibt in Deutschland zwei Branchen, die sich -meiner Meinung nach- durch ganz besonders kreative Wortschöpfungen abheben. Das sind Friseure (Haarmonie, ExemplHaar, Haartist, Haarscharf, um nur ein paar zu nennen) und Gastronomie (Hüftgold, zum Fressack, SansiBar, Thai Tanic, Wok this way, etc.).

Das hängt möglicherweise mit der großen Konkurrenz auf beiden Sektoren zusammen und dem Versuch, sich von der Masse abzuheben

Comment: Zur Existent des Wortes: Siehe meinen [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39087/bedeutung-von-fresslich#comment96420_39088) zu IQVs Antwort, sowie den [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39087/bedeutung-von-fresslich#comment96415_39087), den ich zur Frage selbst geschrieben habe.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis zu meiner Faulheit (bezüglich Suche zur Existenz des Wortes). Ich habe den Text entsprechend angepasst.

Answer (score 2):

Das Adjektiv *fresslich* steht zwar nicht im Wörterbuch, genügt aber den Wortbildungsregeln der deutschen Sprache und ist daher ein richtiges Wort. Es ist vom Verb [*fressen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fressen) abgeleitet und dient hier dazu, das Wohl einzugrenzen. Das *fressliche Wohl* ist dasjenige Wohl, das im Zusammenhang mit dem Fressen, also der Nahrungsaufnahme, steht. Bekannter ist die Wendung *[leibliches](https://www.dwds.de/wb/leiblich) Wohl*. Vielleicht wollten die Autoren einfach kreativ sein und ein anderes Adjektiv verwenden. Allerdings wird *fressen* eher, aber nicht ausschließlich, bei Tieren verwendet, wohingegen Menschen für gewöhnlich *essen*.

Comment: Ist schon wieder jemand unterwegs, der wahrlos Antworten abwertet?

Answer (score 1):

Es handelt sich um ein heute ungewöhnliches Wort, das aber immerhin im [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF08715#XGF08715) noch zu finden ist und mit einem Luther Zitat belegt ist:

> Der freszliche und saufliche Gott.

Nach Grimms soll es in der lateinischen Bedeutung *edulis* (essbar) verwendet worden sein, dem Zitat möchte ich aber eher eine Bedeutung *dem Essen zugeneigt* annehmen.